# Three.js- How can I limit the cameras view in a 3D scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

I added first person controls to a three.js scene. I want to limit the camera views so that the ends of the scene aren't shown. I'm using the firstpersoncontrols.js from the three.js library, which includes mouse, W,A,S,D and arrow controls.  How can limit the camera views with the controls?  I already tried to limit the control distance.
Here is what I have so far regarding the camera and controls:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 55, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
            camera.position.set( 30, 30, 100 );
            //
            controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );
                        controls.movementSpeed = 100;
                        controls.enabled=true;
                        controls.maxDistance=50;//no change
                        controls.minDistance=10
                        controls.enablezoom=false;
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baNJGR

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to adjust how far and wide your camera should see, then you can adjust the FOV, near and far parameters ( PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far ) ).

For example, try creating camera with these values(try it on the codepen example ),

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 200 );
```

You can change the FOV to decide width of the camera simulated view and change far parameter to adjust how far the camera should see.

Comment: It didn't work. The skybox was either distorted or the plane was off

Comment: I don't know whether this is your desired result or not. But check this https://codepen.io/HariKrishnanV/pen/ypNZRy

Comment: The camera is still able to go off the scene and it distorts the skybox.

Comment: @redfelix you can set the  `controls.lookVertical = false` if you don't want to go up and down . See here : [link](https://codepen.io/HariKrishnanV/pen/ypNZRy?editors=1111)

Comment: @redfelix please refer these :  [Example1](http://isaacsukin.com/news/2012/06/how-build-first-person-shooter-browser-threejs-and-webglhtml5-canvas), [Example2](http://icecreamyou.github.io/Nemesis/)